# three20 pain points

Tags: three20

Sorry if this is not the right forum to ask this question.

I believe a lot of folks have using three20 to build their iPhone apps so far. Besides the variety of goodies provided by the framework, what are the pain points using it?

To me, I have the following

- the model/datasource/view controller pattern is not flexible. hard to coordinate and passing data/state around
- hard to customize w/o have a deep understanding of how everything works behind the scene
- the different table items not universally fit to both the grouped or plain tableviews
- the navigation is pain in the ass, not able to easily control the life time of views and passing data to other views

Others?

Comment: Given your first line, I'm guessing you knew this isn't the place for such subjective questions, which makes posting this anyways something of a dick move.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I totally agree. the url based navigation in three20 is just horrible and unusable on iPad devices. the url mapping also doesn't follows apple's design patterns (push/pop view controllers)

i tried convincing the three20 team to remove the TTNavigator and do so some project major updates, but I've failed making my points.

I ended up creating a "three20 lite" edition which I use in my apps. https://github.com/aporat/three20lite

These are the "pain points" I've fixed on my fork, which I think are important to integrate into the main project:

1. All sub projects were merged into a single simple project
2. Simplified installation using a CocoaPods (https://github.com/CocoaPods/CocoaPods)
3. XML & JSON extensions merged back into `TTNetwork`
4. `SBSON` is linked as a submodule
5. `TTExtensionLoader` removed
6. Removed YAJL JSON support
7. `TTSplitViewController` removed

Comment: with regard to your project, If i simply install it instead of the original three20, I can make my project work fine without having to change any of the code?